# How do I extract a single variable from a file?

Tags: python, terminal, netcdf

I'm trying to extract a single variable from this data that will tell me the temperature and height from the radar data and I'm trying to run it from the terminal in Linux, but it keeps giving me the error message saying "no such file or directory." Here is my code:

```
ls DataData
cd Desktop
python DataData.py
```

Here are the contents of the file:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:              
(Time: 6, bottom_top: 99, bottom_top_stag: 100, soil_layers_stag: 5, south_north: 128, south_north_stag: 129, west_east: 128, west_east_stag: 129)
Coordinates:
XLAT                 (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 18.0 18.0 ...
XLONG                (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 -62.0 -62.0 ...
XLAT_U               (Time, south_north, west_east_stag) float32 0.0 0.0 ...
XLONG_U              (Time, south_north, west_east_stag) float32 0.0 0.0 ...
XLAT_V               (Time, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 ...
XLONG_V              (Time, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 ...
 Time                 (Time) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5
 bottom_top           (bottom_top) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ...
 bottom_top_stag      (bottom_top_stag) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
 soil_layers_stag     (soil_layers_stag) int64 0 1 2 3 4
 south_north          (south_north) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ...
 south_north_stag     (south_north_stag) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
 west_east            (west_east) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ...
 west_east_stag       (west_east_stag) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...

Data variables:
Times                (Time) |S19 b'2004-12-16_02:00:00' ...
LU_INDEX             (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0     0.0 ...
ZNU                  (Time, bottom_top) float32 0.994949 0.984848 ...
ZNW                  (Time, bottom_top_stag) float32 1.0 0.989899 ...
ZS                   (Time, soil_layers_stag) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
DZS                  (Time, soil_layers_stag) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
VAR_SSO              (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
LAP_HGT              (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
U                    (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east_stag)   float32 -8.0977 ...
V                    (Time, bottom_top, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 -4.92184 ...
W                    (Time, bottom_top_stag, south_north, west_east) float32 -0.0 ...
PH                   (Time, bottom_top_stag, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
PHB                  (Time, bottom_top_stag, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
T                    (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 -2.18884 ...
HFX_FORCE            (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
LH_FORCE             (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
TSK_FORCE            (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
HFX_FORCE_TEND       (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
LH_FORCE_TEND        (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
TSK_FORCE_TEND       (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
MU                   (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 -437.29 ...
MUB                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 38601.9 ...
NEST_POS             (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
TKE                  (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0961436 ...
P                    (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 88.3828 ...
PB                   (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 101345.0 ...
FNM                  (Time, bottom_top) float32 0.0 0.5 0.500001 ...
FNP                  (Time, bottom_top) float32 0.0 0.5 0.499999 ...
RDNW                 (Time, bottom_top) float32 -98.9999 -98.9999 ...
RDN                  (Time, bottom_top) float32 0.0 -98.9999 -99.0002 ...
DNW                  (Time, bottom_top) float32 -0.010101 -0.010101 ...
DN                   (Time, bottom_top) float32 0.0 -0.010101 -0.010101 ...
CFN                  (Time) float32 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
CFN1                 (Time) float32 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5
P_HYD                (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 101339.0 ...
Q2                   (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
T2                   (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
TH2                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
PSFC                 (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 101535.0 ...
U10                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
V10                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
RDX                  (Time) float32 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
RDY                  (Time) float32 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
RESM                 (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
ZETATOP              (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
CF1                  (Time) float32 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
CF2                  (Time) float32 -1.5 -1.5 -1.5 -1.5 -1.5 -1.5
CF3                  (Time) float32 0.500002 0.500002 0.500002 0.500002 ...
ITIMESTEP            (Time) int32 14400 15600 16800 18000 19200 20400
XTIME                (Time) float32 120.0 130.0 140.0 150.0 160.0 170.0
QVAPOR               (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0167233 ...
QCLOUD               (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QRAIN                (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 1.40266e-12 ...
QICE                 (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QSNOW                (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QGRAUP               (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QHAIL                (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QNWFA2D              (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
QNCCN                (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QNCLOUD              (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QNRAIN               (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.00523219 ...
QNICE                (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QNSNOW               (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QNGRAUPEL            (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QNHAIL               (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
QVGRAUPEL            (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
SHDMAX               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SHDMIN               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SNOALB               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
TSLB                 (Time, soil_layers_stag, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
SMOIS                (Time, soil_layers_stag, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
SH2O                 (Time, soil_layers_stag, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
SMCREL               (Time, soil_layers_stag, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
SEAICE               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
XICEM                (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SFROFF               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
UDROFF               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
IVGTYP               (Time, south_north, west_east) int32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
ISLTYP               (Time, south_north, west_east) int32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
VEGFRA               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
GRDFLX               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
ACGRDFLX             (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
ACSNOM               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SNOW                 (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SNOWH                (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
CANWAT               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SSTSK                (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
COSZEN               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 -0.871705 ...
LAI                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
VAR                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
MAPFAC_M             (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
MAPFAC_U             (Time, south_north, west_east_stag) float32 0.0 0.0 ...
MAPFAC_V             (Time, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 ...
MAPFAC_MX            (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
MAPFAC_MY            (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
MAPFAC_UX            (Time, south_north, west_east_stag) float32 1.0 1.0 ...
MAPFAC_UY            (Time, south_north, west_east_stag) float32 1.0 1.0 ...
MAPFAC_VX            (Time, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 1.0 1.0 ...
MF_VX_INV            (Time, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 1.0 1.0 ...
MAPFAC_VY            (Time, south_north_stag, west_east) float32 1.0 1.0 ...
F                    (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 4.49e-05 ...
E                    (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SINALPHA             (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
COSALPHA             (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
HGT                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
 TSK                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 299.8 299.8 ...
 P_TOP                (Time) float32 62938.1 62938.1 62938.1 62938.1 ...
 T00                  (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 P00                  (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 TLP                  (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 TISO                 (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 MAX_MSTFX            (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 MAX_MSTFY            (Time) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
 RAINC                (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
RAINSH               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
RAINNC               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.120844 ...
SNOWNC               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
GRAUPELNC            (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
HAILNC               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
REFL_10CM            (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
CLDFRA               (Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 ...
SWDOWN               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
GLW                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SWNORM               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
OLR                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
ALBEDO               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.08 0.08 ...
CLAT                 (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
ALBBCK               (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.08 0.08 ...
EMISS                (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.98 0.98 ...
NOAHRES              (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
TMN                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 298.95 ...
XLAND                (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 2.0 2.0 2.0 ...
UST                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.335208 ...
PBLH                 (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
HFX                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 8.70271 ...
QFX                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 6.01207e-05 ...
LH                   (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 150.302 ...
ACHFX                (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
ACLHF                (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SNOWC                (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SR                   (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SAVE_TOPO_FROM_REAL  (Time) int32 0 0 0 0 0 0
AFWA_CLOUD_CEIL      (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
AFWA_CAPE            (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
AFWA_ZLFC            (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
AFWA_PLFC            (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
MIDRH_MIN            (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
AFWA_HAIL            (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
AFWA_LLWS            (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
AFWA_TORNADO         (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SEED1                (Time) int32 0 0 0 0 0 0
SEED2                (Time) int32 0 0 0 0 0 0
LANDMASK             (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
LAKEMASK             (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
SST                  (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 299.8 299.8 ...
SST_INPUT            (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
Attributes:
TITLE:  OUTPUT FROM WRF V3.6 MODEL
START_DATE: 2004-12-16_02:00:00
SIMULATION_START_DATE: 2004-12-16_00:00:00
WEST-EAST_GRID_DIMENSION: 129
SOUTH-NORTH_GRID_DIMENSION: 129
BOTTOM-TOP_GRID_DIMENSION: 100
DX: 100.0
DY: 100.0
STOCH_FORCE_OPT: 0
GRIDTYPE: C
DIFF_OPT: 2
KM_OPT: 2
DAMP_OPT: 0
DAMPCOEF: 0.1
KHDIF: 500.0
KVDIF: 500.0
MP_PHYSICS: 18
RA_LW_PHYSICS: 0
RA_SW_PHYSICS: 0
SF_SFCLAY_PHYSICS: 1
SF_SURFACE_PHYSICS: 0
BL_PBL_PHYSICS: 0
CU_PHYSICS: 0
SF_LAKE_PHYSICS: 0
SURFACE_INPUT_SOURCE: 1
SST_UPDATE: 0
GRID_FDDA: 0
GFDDA_INTERVAL_M: 0
GFDDA_END_H: 0
GRID_SFDDA: 0
SGFDDA_INTERVAL_M: 0
SGFDDA_END_H: 0
HYPSOMETRIC_OPT: 2
SF_URBAN_PHYSICS: 0
SHCU_PHYSICS: 0
MFSHCONV: 0
FEEDBACK: 0
SMOOTH_OPTION: 1
SWRAD_SCAT: 1.0
W_DAMPING: 0
DT: 0.5
RADT: 0.0
BLDT: 0.0
CUDT: 0.0
AER_OPT: 0
SWINT_OPT: 0
AER_TYPE: 1
AER_AOD550_OPT: 1
AER_ANGEXP_OPT: 1
AER_SSA_OPT: 1
AER_ASY_OPT: 1
AER_AOD550_VAL: 0.12
AER_ANGEXP_VAL: 1.3
AER_SSA_VAL: 1.4013e-45
AER_ASY_VAL: 1.4013e-45
MOIST_ADV_OPT: 2
SCALAR_ADV_OPT: 2
TKE_ADV_OPT: 2
DIFF_6TH_OPT: 0
DIFF_6TH_FACTOR: 0.12
OBS_NUDGE_OPT: 0
BUCKET_MM: -1.0
BUCKET_J: -1.0
PREC_ACC_DT: 0.0
SF_OCEAN_PHYSICS: 0
ISFTCFLX: 0
ISHALLOW: 0
ISFFLX: 1
ICLOUD: 1
ICLOUD_CU: 0
TRACER_PBLMIX: 1
SCALAR_PBLMIX: 0
GRAV_SETTLING: 0
DFI_OPT: 0
WEST-EAST_PATCH_START_UNSTAG: 1
WEST-EAST_PATCH_END_UNSTAG: 128
WEST-EAST_PATCH_START_STAG: 1
WEST-EAST_PATCH_END_STAG: 129
SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_START_UNSTAG: 1
SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_END_UNSTAG: 128
SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_START_STAG: 1
SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_END_STAG: 129
BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_START_UNSTAG: 1
BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_END_UNSTAG: 99
BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_START_STAG: 1
BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_END_STAG: 100
GRID_ID: 1
PARENT_ID: 0
I_PARENT_START: 1
J_PARENT_START: 1
PARENT_GRID_RATIO: 1
CEN_LAT: 0.0
CEN_LON: 0.0
TRUELAT1: 0.0
TRUELAT2: 0.0
MOAD_CEN_LAT: 0.0
STAND_LON: 0.0
POLE_LAT: 0.0
POLE_LON: 0.0
GMT: 0.0
JULYR: 0
JULDAY: 1
MAP_PROJ: 0
MAP_PROJ_CHAR: Cartesian
MMINLU: 
NUM_LAND_CAT: 24
ISWATER: 0
ISLAKE: 0
ISICE: 0
ISURBAN: 0
ISOILWATER: 0
```

This is when it gives me the error message [Errno 2] no such file or directory. I'm trying to use this code to retrieve the variable from the file, which is below:

```
python DataData.py -o EXPERIMENT_tas.nc --time-units="days since 1949-12-01_00:00:00" -v T2 wrfout1.nc wrfout2.nc ... wrfoutN.nc
```

How do I get the terminal to retrieve the variable and is this the right code to use to get the variable?

Comment: Please show your python file

Comment: I saved the python file as DataData it's a wrf file that I downloaded to my computer is that what you meant?

Comment: Please [edit] with the contents of `DataData.py` and show the traceback of the exception message. Unless `python DataData.py` is what is throwing the error, then you are simply missing the `DataData.py` file in the current directory

Comment: Gotcha sorry about that and I added the contents of the file

Comment: You saved a `.wrf` file (whatever that is) with a Python extension and expect it to work as valid Python code? Is that what I'm reading?

Comment: Yes it came as a wrf file but I saved it as a .py file, but it still won't work. Wrf files are used for scientific data. If I can't run it through the command line as a .py file, how can I retrieve the variable as a wrf file? Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you read that you can execute that file with a Python interpreter?

Comment: This is my assignment: " The task is to visualize simulation data produced by the Weather Research and
 Forecasting Large Eddy Simulation (WRF-LES) model. Data will be provided and the
 deliverable will be in the form of a .py file that can be run on the command
 line:
 
 plot_wrf.py /path/to/input_file.nc /path/to/output/ Variable Level vmim=vmin vmax=vmax"

Comment: Well yeah `plot_wrf.py` is the name of the `.py` file. You can't just take a file that has no valid Python syntax, change the extension, and expect it to work. I don't know what's causing your "file not found" error but the best you can hope for is a SyntaxError if you ever do specify the path correctly.

Comment: Yeah I'm a bit confused myself as that was the assignment I was given by my boss, but thank you for at least looking at it I appreciate your help